# The proof that $\kappa$ is the only measurable in L[U]

Tags: set-theory

Let $\kappa$ be measurable and $U$ be its normal measure. I didn't understand a step in the proof that $\kappa$ is the only measurable cardinal in $L[U]$.

So suppose there is another measurable $\lambda < \kappa$ such that $\lambda$ is measurable in  $L[U]$. Then we consider the elementary embedding $j: L[U] \rightarrow M$ given by $\lambda$. We now wish to show that $j(U) = U\cap M$. As $\kappa$ is a strong limit with $cf(\kappa) > \lambda$, $j(\kappa)=\kappa$. Then the textbook (e.g., Kanamori p 262) says that $U\cap M \subseteq j(U)$ **since** $j(U)$ is an ultrafilter on $\kappa$ in $M$. I don't see how this follows. What am I missing here?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $j(U)$ is an ultrafilter on $\kappa$ in $M$, for every $A\subseteq\kappa$ that is in $M$, either $A\in j(U)$ or $\kappa\setminus A\in j(U)$.  This means we cannot have a strict inclusion $j(U)\subset U\cap M$, since the only way $U\cap M$ could be strictly larger is to contain both a set and its complement, which is impossible since $U$ is a proper filter.  So once you show $j(U)\subseteq U\cap M$, you also get the reverse inclusion for free.